# How to cast a mock object using PowerMockito

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

My method is having following line -

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); //1
JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(details); //2
((ObjectNode) root).put("userId", userId); //3
```

I am trying to write a stub for above line #3 and it is getting fail by saying ClassCastException -

```
@Mock
JsonNode                mockJsonNode;

@Mock
ObjectNode              mockObjectNode;

ObjectMapper mockMapper = PowerMockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(ObjectMapper.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockMapper);
PowerMockito.when(mockMapper.readTree(Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(mockJsonNode);
PowerMockito.when(mockObjectNode.put(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockObjectNode);
```

I understand as its giving exception because there is no relation between a mock object and actual object but what is the way to write stub for line#3?

This is the complete exception -

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$26691c0b cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared

```
JsonNode                mockJsonNode;
```

So your mocking framework will make sure that mockJsonNode is "exactly" of that type **JsonNode**.

Keep in mind: a **cast** is nothing else but telling the compiler "he, you compiler, that object X that you think has type Y, in reality it has type Z". In order to make that work, X actually must be a Z at runtime.

So, the simple solution could be to change that declaration to:

```
ObjectNode mockJsonNode
```

In other words: your production code **assumess** that the result returned by `readTree()` is actually an instance of *ObjectNode*. Then, of course you have to make sure that your mocking framework actually returns something that is an *ObjectNode*.